# Render Blob as State with this.setState() and render Image in DOM

Tags: reactjs

I want to render an Image on the DOM after the upload button is pressed. My attempt was to set the state of imageSource to file and render that in the dom but I get an 'Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1' error. Any help as to how I can find a work around ? The extra details I'm beginning to write is just to satisfy stackoverflow's details limit. I have pretty much explained myself.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Generator.css';


class Generator extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            imageSource: './image/image.svg'
        }
        this.fileUpload = this.fileUpload.bind(this)
        this.fileSelected = this.fileSelected.bind(this)
    }

    fileUpload(){
        var preview = document.querySelector('img');
        var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
        var reader  = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
          preview.src = reader.result;
          this.setState({imageSource: JSON.parse(file) }) 
          console.log(this.state.imageSource)
        console.log(file)
        }, false);

        if (file) {
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }    }

    fileSelected(){
        console.log(this.state.imageSource)
    }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="container">
                <div className="card-body">
                    <h6 className="card-subtitle text-muted pt-1">Generate a Colin Kaepernick Nike Campaign Meme Fast and Easy</h6>
                </div>

                <img className="mx-auto d-block pb-2" src={require(`${this.state.imageSource}`)}  alt=""></img>  
        </div>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <div className="form-group pt-5">
                    <label htmlFor="quote">Type in your quote</label>
                    <textarea className="form-control" id="quote" rows="2" placeholder="Type your quote here..." ></textarea>
                </div>   
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <div className="btn-toolbar d-block justify-content-center p-2">  
            <div className="btn-group mr-2">
                <button onClick={() => this.fileUpload.click()} type="button" className="btn btn-primary">UPLOAD IMAGE</button>
            </div>
            <div className="btn-group mr-2">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success">GENERATE</button>
            </div>   
            <div className="form-group">
                <input ref={fileUpload => this.fileUpload = fileUpload} style={{display: 'none'}} type="file" onChange={this.fileUpload}/>              
            </div>           
        </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Generator;
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `JSON.parse()` in your readers `load` event handler, is throwing this error because the `file` variable is not a string.

To update the `imageSource` state of your component via `setState()`, you can make the following adjustment:

```
   reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
      preview.src = reader.result;

      this.setState({imageSource: file })  // Remove JSON.parse

      console.log(this.state.imageSource)
      console.log(file)
    }, false);
```

Also in your HTML markup, consider adjusting the `<img/>` element by updating the `src` attribute and adjusting the closing bracket like so:

```
<img className="mx-auto d-block pb-2" src={this.state.imageSource}  alt="" />
```